# Thymeleaf: calling JavaScript function with th:onclick - 'Uncaught ReferenceError'

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf

> JavaScript: "Uncaught ReferenceError: getMenuResults is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BovfK.png)

Code:

```
<div>
  <a
    th:each="menu : ${menus}"
    th:onclick="getMenu([[${menu.dictId}]])"
    th:text="${menu.dictName}"
  ></a>
</div>
```

```
<script>

  function getMenu(menuId) {
    console.log('menuId')
  }

</script>
```

I want to call javascript function using th:onclick, but every time error "Uncaught ReferenceError: getMenuResults is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick" is occuring.
I tried everything on internet, tried to use another answers in StackOverflow, but error did not disappear.

Comment: Just make sure, `getMenu` is available in global scope. Inside of browser `console` tab, call the `getMenu` function with arbitrary value.

Comment: In console, it is working. That is why I'm at a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted and cloned the project again, and it started to work. It was a problem in IDE. That is why I got this error.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly access menu as below by adding onclick attribute

```
<div>
  <a
    th:each="menu : ${menus}"
    th:attr="onclick=|javascript:getMenu('${menu.dictId}')|" 
    th:text="${menu.dictName}"
  ></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I know how to use onclick, problem is my HTML can not find javascript function

Comment: where you have written the js code ...in thymeleaf page or in separate JS file? Could you please share screenshot of your actual code or full page error

Comment: They both are in one HTML file which is written using thymeleaf.

Comment: Not worked on my case

Comment: Could you please share your code ?

Comment: @Yokesh I deleted and cloned the project again, and it started to work